# Rotate and move with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to rotate and move an image at the same time, actually works just one time, but then just move and not rotating.

This is what i have:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8">
  <title>JQuery Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(MyMain);
      function MyMain(){ 

        $(".cartman").hover(MoveCartman,Normal);   //on hover Eric  Cartman

        var v1=100;   //variable to move Cartman

        function MoveCartman(){
          $(this).attr("src","CartmanNude.png");
          $(this).css({
            "margin-top":v1+"px",
            "transform":"rotateZ(-360deg)",
            "transition":"1s"
           });
          if (v1<200){v1+=100;}
          else {v1=0;}
        }
        function Normal(){
          $(this).attr("src","CartmanNormal.png");
        }

        }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="padding:0px">
        <img class="img-responsive cartman" src="CartmanNormal.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this should work fine but I dont know why the function on hover is not working more than just 1 time.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting lowercase `d` for `D` at `doctype` declaration , adding `all` to `transition` value before duration ; `css` `"margin-top": "0px"` , `"transform": "rotateZ(0deg)"` to `Normal` function

```css
.cartman {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JQuery Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(MyMain);

    function MyMain() {

      $(".cartman").hover(MoveCartman, Normal); //on hover Eric  Cartman

      var v1 = 100; //variable to move Cartman

      function MoveCartman() {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats");
        $(this).css({
          "margin-top": v1 + "px",
          "transform": "rotateZ(-360deg)"
        });
        if (v1 < 200) {
          v1 += 100;
        } else {
          v1 = 0;
        }
      }

      function Normal() {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics")
          .css({
            "margin-top": "0px",
            "transform": "rotateZ(0deg)"
          });
      }

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="padding:0px">
        <img class="img-responsive cartman" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/yp9009fm/ ..  .. back rotate and transition to 0 ..I created it may help someone else :)